# restore a mongo db from connection string into local database

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

I have a QA database that has more up to date documents in the cluster than there is on the database on my local machine. I want to do the restore via the QA connection string that I have i.e 
`mongodb://somePortalAPI:***@SomeServer` into my local database using MonngoDB Compass.

From the research I have came across online, I only see backup and restores being done using a dump of the existing dbs through the Mongo shell which is not what I want to do in my case.

I want to restore the QA connection string into my local database in MongoDB Compass.

Comment: Compass wasn't designed for backup/restore, mongodump and mongorestore were.

Comment: @Harold_Finch If its just a collection, you can export and import from the Compass.

Comment: @prasad_ I will look at exploring this and revert back once I find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

This solved it:

C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin>mongorestore.exe --archive="

The zip folder is my backup dump.